# How to connect to a wireless display (an Epson EB-2250U projector) with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, display, linux-mint, projector

Taking the guide from [How to connect to a wireless display (my Smart TV) with Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312200/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-display-my-smart-tv-with-linux-mint/):
I am in the same network as the projector. I have GNOME Network Displays installed.

I could connect to my home with the same settings, but now, I cannot connect to the Epson EB-2250U projector, even though I can connect with my iPad and iPhone. How do I find the projector as network display? Is there a button on the remote control I have to press? There is also an Apple TV mini computer attached to the projector:

[image]

I might be able to find that in the WLAN and then share my screen with it. If someone knows such a workaround, it can also be an accepted answer - unless I can find a fix to connect to the projector without a third device.

I have Linux Mint 20.04. But this should be about changing the projector settings since it does not seem to send a signal that Linux can read. Therefore, it seems to be better here on Super User.

Comment: I don't even know if this is the right question, but does your computer support wireless display technology at the hardware level? WiDi has a few brand names (Miracast is one of the better known). I'd look up specs on your computer hardware to confirm it supports this.

Comment: @music2myear I remember vaguely having tried the Miracast standard, but now I cannot check this anymore since I do no longer have these devices in question at hand. I leave the question to those who run into this as well, and Miracast might even fix all of this, but I cannot check the answers and remarks anymore.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes they no longer have this hardware and so cannot replicate the problem or confirm a solution.

Comment: @music2myear I guess that you only stick to the rules of this being off-topic. Yet, I disagree with closing this one. I have spent many hours on trying to setup many projectors in many settings. I did not get an answer to this one while I needed one, and as you see, nobody has answered or even dropped a remark for half a year until I changed one tiny thing and by this, brought it up the list. The problem in question is still there, it is just at another working place that I do not visit anymore. I cannot check it, but the question stays the same.

Comment: At that time, I have dealt with a lot of projector problems and also asked two other questions, see [How to connect to a wireless display (an Epson EB-2250U projector) with Linux Mint](https://superuser.com/questions/1808570/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-display-an-epson-eb-2250u-projector-with-linux-mi), [Epson EB-2250U projector shows black=blank screen after connecting from a device with WLAN](https://superuser.com/questions/1808585/epson-eb-2250u-projector-shows-black-blank-screen-after-connecting-from-a-device). I tried many apps and settings.