# Epson EB-2250U projector shows black=blank screen after connecting from a device with WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, projector

What to do if an Epson EB-2250U projector shows only a blank screen (=nothing) as soon as a device connects with it over WLAN? It works with devices sending over HDMI cable.

I checked the Epson guide [Solutions When No Image Appears](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd53624/source/troubleshooting/reference/problem_no_image.html), to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing this with the small chance that it works for others and is not just a placebo. It seems as if I could fix this by stopping the synchronization (~ "screen doubling") to the projector. After a while, it then only showed very few network points even though before, I had a longer list. When I then tried to connect to the projector in that room again, it failed. After waiting a few seconds, the WLAN showed all of the network points again, and after this sort of "restart" of the WLAN points, it worked again. I do not know what happened there, and it could not be anything from outside like an admin doing this since it was late in the evening.